# how to convert a print loop function into a final string from dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I make the print loop add together to form a string with spaces?

```
positions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 9, 10]
words = ['this', 'is', 'not', 'howr', 'needed', 'and', 'it', 'wrong', 'right', ':(']
poswords = dict(zip(positions, words))
print(poswords, words)
for i in positions: 
    print(poswords[i]," ",)
```

When I simply want the print to be saved in a string

Comment: `positions` is not defined, what is it?

Comment: Explain better please, Do you want to output: "This is not howr needed and it wrong right :(" and "1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 2 8 6 3 9 10"?

Comment: When the segment is ran the code will spit out the words on a new line. I need it to be in a variable to print onto a single line

Comment: Look into `join` - `' '.join(poswords)` will get you where you want, I think...

Comment: also, look into DSU (decorate-sort-undecorate) pattern...

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence =  " ".join([words[i-1] for i in positions]) #?
```

yields:

> 'this is not howr this is needed and it is wrong and not right :('

Comment: forgot to mention this is python 3

Comment: OP counts positions from 1, so it should be `words[i-1]`

Comment: Thank you,  fixed.

Answer (score 0):

@AShelly's answer is the ideal solution, but if you would prefer to use the loop then you can use the following:

```
positions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 8, 6, 3, 9, 10]
words = ['this', 'is', 'not', 'howr', 'needed', 'and', 'it', 'wrong', 'right', ':(']
for i in positions: 
    print(words[i-1], end = ' ')
```

The named parameter of print (`end = ' '`) means that the `print` statement will end with a `' '` rather than the usual `'\n'`.